# Estimation of determinant for $ |g_{ij} -\delta_{ij}|\le \epsilon$

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite

Let $\delta_{ij}= 1$ when $i=j$, otherwise $\delta_{ij}=0$. And $g_{ij}=g_{ji}$.  The  $ |g_{ij} -\delta_{ij}|\le \epsilon$  means that
$\forall v=(v_1,...,v_n)\in \mathbb R^n$  there is
$$
\left|\sum_{i,j=1}^n v_i(g_{ij}-\delta_{ij})v_j  \right|\le \epsilon\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2
\tag{1}
$$
where $|\cdot|$ of (1) is absolute value (the following symbol $|\cdot|$ also represents absolute value).
I am interested in understanding the inequality for $\det(g_{ij})$ when the  $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small.

For $n=2$, I guess
$$
|\det(g_{ij})|\le (1+\epsilon)^2
$$
But I don't know how to prove. I guess the above inequality just by trying some examples.

Besides, for general $n$, I feel there should be
$$
|\det(g_{ij})|\le (1+\epsilon)^n
$$

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but if you have $1+\epsilon$ on the main diagonal and $0$ otherwise then the determinant is $(1+\epsilon)^n$

Comment: @Salcio  Yes, in fact, we also need the low boundary, else, there is counter-example.

Comment: Is $|A|$ the determinant of $A$? Or the operator norm of $A$? I suppose it's the former because you tagged the question with "determinant," but it would be good to clarify in the body of the question

Comment: @AlexOrtiz  Yes, but just to avoid confusion, I use "det" to represent the determinant. And based on Salcio's comment, I think my initial assumption was incorrect. Therefore, I have edited it.

Comment: Are you assuming that $g$ is symmetric? If so, take advantage of the fact that it is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Deane  It is symmetric. Thanks.